# How to Execute Multiple SSIS packages at a single time in production

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have 20 SSIS packages and want to put all packages in a single package to run as  a single package with same destination table.Is that possible? If possible Can anyone help me how?

Comment: Yes it is possible but it seems to me you haven't made any effort to work it out. Have you create a master package yet?

Comment: As @Nick.McDermaid said use a MasterPackage and inside the Master package use ExecutePackageTask which can call other package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Execute Package Task
Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task-editor

or you can execute from script Task

```
public void Main()
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
        Package package = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\OptionalFolderButSlashRequired\ChildPackage", "server", null, null, null);
    }
```